# how can I lay out the drawing object on the specific Relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout, android-drawable

I have a FrameLayout and I added a RelativeLayout to it. I have some buttons in my relative layout. and I can change their position related to the relativeLayout with this code:

```
ibrllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ibrllp.topMargin=0;
ibrllp.leftMargin=0;
ib = new ImageButton(this);
ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
ib.setLayoutParams(ibrllp);
rl.addView(ib);
```

I want to add a imageView and draw some lines on this relativeLayout. with this code:

```
rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
fllp =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(600,400);
fllp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
rl.setLayoutParams(fllp);

ibllpImageView= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ibllpImageView.topMargin=100;
ibllpImageView.leftMargin=100;

drawingImageView = new ImageView(this);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
  .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
  .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
drawingImageView.setLayoutParams(ibllpImageView);

rl.addView(drawingImageView); 
canvas.drawLine(0, 0 , 400, 400, paint);
```

It draw a line But in a wrong position. I want to able to set coordinate of start point of the line related to the ralativeLayout. just like buttons ... but I can't ... 
this code is my Xml:

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4Chob"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/purple"
    android:layout_weight="0.43" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4Chob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="414dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blue" >         
    </RelativeLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

where is the problem?